# How to know when a jquery effect ends if there are mutiple elements which are animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate, jquery-deferred

Given the following example: If 5 `<li>` elements are found, the callback fires an alert **5 times**...

Is there an easy way to find out when the animation is really over and just **fire once**?

```
$(this).parent().siblings('li').slideUp(500,function(){
    alert 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.when($(this).parent().siblings('li').slideUp(500))
 .then(function() {
            alert('Finished!');
       });
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyHxZ/)

`when` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Comment: sweet! Thanks a lot! Seemed to be a good question and a good answer ;-P Thats fun!

Comment: ATTENTION this works not with Jquery 1.4.4...but with 1.7.1!!

Comment: @Jurudocs **lol**, what a drama! And no, It works with **1.5+**. Which is one year old(released on _January 31, 2011_), update your jQuery version please...

Comment: do you know why this error comes up "$(this).parent().siblings("li").slideUp(500).then is not a function" when i try this: "                    $.when($(this).parent().siblings('li').slideUp(500).then(function(){
                        alert('end');
                    }));"

Comment: @Jurudocs. Yes, You mixed with the **parentheses** => `$.when($(this).parent().siblings('li').slideUp(500)).then(function() {
    alert('end');
});​` Write with editor that highlight parentheses...

Comment: nice thanks man! Great help! This comes pretty handy with other problems too!